# bei vs in Firma

Tags: english-to-german, difference, standard-german

Sentence is:

> I am an intern in your company.

I wrote:

> Ich bin eine Praktikantin **bei** ihrer Firma.

Translator shows:

> Ich bin einen Praktikantin **in** Ihrer Firma.

I learnt that while using company, we should always use "**bei**".
One more thing, female intern = "**eine** Praktikantin" but why the translator shows "**einen** Praktikantin".

Sorry, the usage of these preposition is sometime confusing to me.

Kindly explain. Thank you.

Comment: Since you seem to get a habit of using *vs* in the title of questions: *vs* is imo incomplete even in English and would require a dot indicating abbreviation. In German it is far less common and I would recommend to use something like *oder*, *gegenüber* or similar instead. The differences tag would also help (added that).

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the translator is wrong. Your explanations are correct:

> [...] [W]hile using company, we should always use *bei*.

Note: *von* would sometimes be an alternative.

> female intern = *eine* Praktikantin

Comment: Might be a regional thing, but IMO _bei_ and _in_ are both acceptable and have the same meaning here (if you ignore the obscure possibility of an intern from elsewhere being just accidentially located in the building).

Answer (score 1):

Talking about a named company like *VW* or *Aldi*, you will use the preposition *bei*:

> Ich bin Praktikantin bei VW. Ich arbeite bei Aldi als Kassiererin. Er ist Techniker bei der Telekom.

If the listener(s) are working in the same company as you, you can say

> Ich bin hier Praktikantin / Ich arbeite hier als Praktikantin / Ich in hier als Praktikantin eingesetzt.

Talking to the boss, you could say

> Ich arbeite bei Ihnen als Praktikantin / Ich bin Praktikantin in Ihrem Unternehmen.

As the possessive article does not imply a strict possessive relationship but in most cases is meaning just a membership or an affiliation, you can also use these sentences addressing to your collegues. But then, you would say rather 'ihr' than 'Sie':

> Ich arbeite bei euch als Praktikantin / Ich bin Praktikantin in eurer Firma.

Talking about an economic branch, the preposition may vary

- sie arbeitet im Buchhandel / im Gesundheitsdienst / in der Gastronomie / im Schuldienst / im Gartenbau / in der Landwirtschaft / im Einzelhandel ...
- ich arbeite beim Radio / bei der Zeitung / beim Fernsehen / bei der Post / bei der Bahn / bei der Polizei (*institutions*)
- er arbeitet am Theater / an der Uni
- er arbeitet auf dem Bau (coll.) / auf der Zeche / auf der Werft

A single not-named Company may be referred to like this:

> Sie arbeitet in einem großen Energieversorgungsunternehmen / in einer Apotheke / an einer großen französischen Eliteschule / auf einem Bauernhof

As long as we don't have rules for all that one must learn those expressions like vocables. As you go along with it, the rules will be forming themselves within your unexpressed (internal) grammar - we call it '*Sprachgefühl*'.

So, my answer to your specific question would be:

> Talking about your internship in your actual company, I would neither choose the preposition *in* nor *bei*, but say *Ich bin hier Praktikantin* or *Ich bin hier bei euch Praktikantin.* Note that a profession or a function or a job in German comes without an article: *Ich arbeite hier als Krankenpflegehelferin / als Auszubildende / als Praktikantin* or *Ich bin hier Praktikantin / Mitarbeiterin auf Zeit ...* For me *Ich bin Praktikantin bei Ihrer Firma* would have the wrong preposition. *Ich bin Praktikantin in Ihrer Firma* is correct if the important thing you want to say is **in Ihrer Firma**, otherwise you should say *Ich bin hier (nur) Praktikantin.* If you want to introduce youself to your new collegues you can say: *Ich bin neu hier, ich mache hier (bei euch) ein Praktikum.*